# Perforce cannot unshelve more than once?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am new to Perforce. One day a coworker used shelve command to share some code change with me. I unshelved the change and modified a couple of small issues of his code change. One day later, he shelved some new changes on the same set of files from last time. I tried to unshelve the changes, but this time Perforce reported error on every file that I have made corrections:

> "Librarian checkout _some_path_ failed.  open for read: _some_path_,d/1._pending_changelist_number.gz: No such file or directory"

I did some search for answers, but none of them do I fully understand.

My understanding of this problem is:

Let's say file A has shelved changes ABC from dude X.
I pick the changes up, and edit this file A. Let's call the new file A the A*.

Since shelve is design for working in a temporary sense, there will be no history recorded by Perforce.
Dude X shelves more changes DEF to file A. I would like to pick them up.

When Perforce unshelving, it basically does a merge. DEF should be merged to file A. However, Perforce sees A* instead of A.

Perforce panic.

Can someone help me understand the mechanism?

Comment: What you describe should work fine; the error you're getting indicates that the shelf was deleted on the server side (you'd get this error if someone went directly into the server's data store and deleted some of the files corresponding to the shelf, rather than using "p4 shelve -d" to delete the shelf cleanly from the client side).  Does that sound like a possibility?

Comment: @SamStafford agree. I need to double check with admin. So picking up shelved changes from someone else's pending changelist should be totally fine,  right? I would imagine it is just like how you cherry pick a commit in git.

Comment: Yes, when you unshelve into an open file it should simply merge the shelf contents (i.e. the diff between the shelved rev and the depot rev it's based on) into your local file, making no assumptions about what your local file contains (it's always assumed that a file that's open for edit might contain absolutely anything).